# Rightmost decimal digits of Graham's number

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion, tetration, big-numbers

How to find rightmost $n$ decimal digits of Graham's number **efficiently**.

The last 500 digits are on the [wiki/Graham's_number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number), but I want to know more.

PowerTowerMod seems to be able to do it but is not very efficient, is there a better way?

```
Block[
 {$RecursionLimit = Infinity},
 ResourceFunction["PowerTowerMod"][
  3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^3^\
3^3^3^3^3^3^3, 10^500]
]
```

And the recursion deadline is not very clear

Comment: @ciao well, then the problem is, why 600?

Comment: The problem here is to find a better algorithm; that's not really a MMA problem. Maybe this question should really be asked on a different forum.

Comment: There are 16 million rightmost digits available online. Perhaps avail yourself of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number#Rightmost_decimal_digits) and the [wikia](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number#Calculating_last_digits) state, a simple algorithm for computing the last $n$ digits is given by:

$$N(0)=3\\N(m+1)=3^{N(m)}\bmod10^{m+1}$$

Here, $N(m)$ is the last $m$ digits. This is the same algorithm given in [Is this the correct way to compute the last $n$
digits of Graham's number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1821469/272831). Example python code:

```
def powmod(exp, mod, base = 3):

    # Assume base = 3 and mod = 10^m
    # and apply Euler's totient theorem

    exp %= mod * 2 // 5

    # Exponentiate by squaring
    res = 1

    while exp > 0:
        if exp % 2 == 1:
            res = res * base % mod
        base = base * base % mod
        exp //= 2
    return res

def lastdigits(m):
    res = 3
    for i in range(1, m+1):
        res = powmod(res, pow(10, i))
    return res
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bVHBasMwDL3nKwSjLO4y4jT0Mshgh/7GwCNKYkhs13Zo/fWZ7ISmsOkgy9bTe5Jsgh@0qt9NMGFZWuzA6Nuk2xzvpgAKCvgRDqGBmn1kQJbcC3w5N0/4SIJQbYRTXPHvaQPFR2HMGOAyj2hfHXjtJSoPfkBtcdoZSQ8OTaI4wgnKEs7Pcpe70YoKpfAkGsBdZ2Gl6lPaoou6O/42yBET5Sfwte1osltliL8h/J7YSaI/rlMdYjMPyDZoOv4FROaybOC0teRnqyJdlsWtjsL5VvbSu3zaFrkK1inutAUJkgqE6jGvaPVvFdsbXLHb19CliHFe8QIkY38EDW3G50@SZ84ZW5Zf)